# NIToolbarPhotoViewController with photos in app bundle

Tags: ios, nimbus-ios, photoviewer

Originally posted at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nimbusios/nGePpdl12N4/Etnyp1cUOhMJ

Are there any examples available using `NIToolbarPhotoViewController` 
with non-network images?  I have the images in my application bundle 
that I would like to present through this class.  I have tried a few 
tweaks of the NetworkPhotoAlbum example with my own subclass 
(subclassing `NIToolbarPhotoViewController` directly, not 
`NetworkPhotoAlbumViewController`).  However, even when I hardcode the 
following two methods in my subclass to return an image using + 
imageNamed, I get blank screen.

```
- (UIImage *)photoAlbumScrollView: (NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoAlbumScrollView 
                     photoAtIndex: (NSInteger)photoIndex 
                        photoSize: (NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSize *)photoSize 
                        isLoading: (BOOL *)isLoading 
          originalPhotoDimensions: (CGSize *)originalPhotoDimensions 

- (UIImage *)photoScrubberView: (NIPhotoScrubberView *)photoScrubberView 
              thumbnailAtIndex: (NSInteger)thumbnailIndex
```

Based on my current understanding, it seems that any class should be 
able to subclass `NIToolbarPhotoViewController` and implement these two 
methods below as a very basic start.  However, even with these two 
datasource methods implemented as shown, I receive a blank screen. 
Though, I still get the view showing the correct photo count (4 of 10, 
for example) and can click through using the forward/back arrows, I 
end up with no actuall images displaying.  I was expecting the 
default.png to show up 10 times.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoScrollView:(NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoScrollView { 
  return 10; 
} 

- (UIImage *)photoAlbumScrollView: (NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoAlbumScrollView 
                     photoAtIndex: (NSInteger)photoIndex 
                        photoSize: (NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSize *)photoSize 
                        isLoading: (BOOL *)isLoading 
          originalPhotoDimensions: (CGSize *)originalPhotoDimensions { 

  return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: 
     NIPathForBundleResource(nil, @"NimbusPhotos.bundle/gfx/default.png")]; 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem.  You need to assign a value to the photoSize (and originalPhotoDimensions should also be set, but it is not essential).  I would have thought that the default behavior would have been to read the properties off of the image directly, but the default is (0,0).

```
- (UIImage *)photoAlbumScrollView: (NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoAlbumScrollView 
                 photoAtIndex: (NSInteger)photoIndex 
                    photoSize: (NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSize *)photoSize 
                    isLoading: (BOOL *)isLoading 
      originalPhotoDimensions: (CGSize *)originalPhotoDimensions { 

 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: 
 NIPathForBundleResource(nil, @"NimbusPhotos.bundle/gfx/default.png")];

 *originalPhotoDimensions = [image size];
 *photoSize = NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSizeOriginal;
 return image;}
```

This did the trick for me, it should for anyone else as well.

Comment: I forgot to type "return image;" in the sample.

Comment: you are the man, pulling my hair out with this one til found this post. thank you